# Як найкраще перекласти “fake”?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Останнім часом це слово набуло особливої актуальності коли мова йде про новини чи [підставні](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidstavnyj) профілі у соцмережах.

Я схиляюсь до варіанту “[фальшивка](http://sum.in.ua/s/faljshyvka)”, коли іде мова про вигадані події, та, власне, підставний профіль. Але, можливо, є кращі, більш лаконічні, варіанти

Comment: Пряме запозичення *"фейк"* разом із похідними як-то *"фейковий"* наразі набирають популярності. У словниках, щоправда, цього ще нема, але ймовірно, що з'явиться.

Comment: мені здається, потрібно перекладати за контекстом. Новини можуть бути *неправдивими*  (або *брехливими*, або *сфабрикованими*), профіль — *підставним*. В англійській мові просто *fabricated news* довго писати, вони навіть *ветеранів* скоротили до *ветів*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Липові новини, липовий профіль.

Зі статті [липовий](http://sum.in.ua/s/lypovyj) у СУМ-11:

> 3. *перен., розм.* Підроблений, несправжній. — Звуть його — Яків, трохи кульгає, прізвища не пам'ятаю, воно в нього липове (Юрій Яновський, I,
>    1954, 226); — Виявилось, коли ми перевірили роботу Званова, що ударник
>    з нього липовий (Олесь Донченко, II, 1956, 120).

Зі статті [липа](http://sum.in.ua/s/lypa)  у СУМ-11:

> 2. *перен.* Про що-небудь фальшиве, підроблено.
>
> ♦ **Липу справляти** — обдурювати, підробляти (здебільшого документи). — Я можу від лікарів
> посвідчення подати, що інвалід війни! — зухвало озвався Шпулька. — За
> півсотні мені яку завгодно липу на Галицькому базарі справлять (Юрій
> Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 329).

А от і приклади вжитку з інтернету:

- [Як відрізнити "липові" новини від справжніх](http://znaj.ua/news/regions/89248/ak-vidrizniti-lipovi-novini-vid-spravzhnih.html)
- [Полювання на липових пільговиків](http://wz.lviv.ua/economics/160566-poliuvannia-na-lypovykh-pilhovykiv)

---

Ось також цікавий запис із поясненням походження знайшов у *Фразеологічний словник східнослобожанських і степових говірок Донбасу / Віктор Ужченко, Дмитро Ужченко* (2013).

> **Липу справляти (трусити, давати нюхати)**, *жарг*. Обдурю- вати,
> підробляти (перев. про документи). Михай, Молгв. • В арго **липа** –
> „фальшивий, підроблений документ”. Тісно пов’язане зі сло- вом *липок* –
> „у грі шулерів липка мазь, якою склеюються дві карти”;
> *липкове очко* – наклеєне цією ж маззю очко, котре легко відстає,
> якщо зачепити його пальцем (В. Даль); **липуха** – „фальшиве
> посвідчення”.

Comment: Думав над цим варіантом і у мене були схожі думки на рахунок калькування. Знайшов тут обговорення етимології цього слова: http://rus.stackexchange.com/a/29691

Comment: @meenternet, ще це: http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/8462/177516 — хоча мені rusSE не завжди подобається.

Answer (score 9):

В Вікіпедії є стаття [Фейкові новини](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8):

> Фейкові новини — повністю або частково вигадана інформація про
>   суспільні події, явища, певних осіб, яка подається у ЗМІ під виглядом
>   справжніх журналістських матеріалів. Часто носять *гумористичний* або
>   *сатиричний* характер і створюються з метою висміювання або привернення
>   уваги до важливих суспільних проблем чи тенденцій.
>
> Як синонім до поняття вживається термін *«журналістська качка»* або
>   латинське словосполучення «non testatur» чи його скорочення NT, що в
>   перекладі означає «не перевірено». За однією з версій термін сам
>   «качка» був введений на початку XVI ст. ідеологом протестантизму
>   Мартіном Лютером, який одного разу замість «legende» («легенда»)
>   чомусь написав слово «lugemde», а воно німцями сприймалося як
>   «брехлива качка».

Прикладом ресурсу, що публікує фейкові новини є [UaReview](http://uareview.com/).

Хочу зазначити, що фейкові акаунти в соціальних мережах називають *ботами*, або *****ботами*, якщо вони створені для роботи на конкретну організацію чи людину.

Answer (score 4):

Перше, що спадає на думку - слово [*облуда*](http://sum.in.ua/s/obluda), яке має наступні значення:

> 1. *розм.* Удавання, лицемірство з метою обдурювання; фальш, неправда.
> 2. *розм.* Нещира людина; лицемір.
> 3. *розм.* Те, що відчувається, уявляється, привиджується; примара, мана.
> 4. *діал.* Зовнішній вигляд; оболонка.